# amChart legend appearance

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have an amChart with many rows, like this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/tWfk8/1/). The legend looks a bit awfull.

Is it possible to display the legend in a single row with some scrolling? like for the [columns](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#maxColumns)? (I don't want to change the container div's `height`)

Comment: my last hours try seems that AMcharts serial type hasn't legend for **every categoryAxis** ((but if you want to add another graphs you can/have/(do it) for every graph to select and show or hide selected graph))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is too old to answer but still it may help someone to get rid of this problem quickly.

Following is the proper documentation provided by amcharts:
[`https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/putting-a-legend-outside-the-chart-area/`](https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/putting-a-legend-outside-the-chart-area/)

And here is the JsFiddle Example: [`http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/Cww3D/`](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/Cww3D/)

HTML:

```
Chart div:
<div id="chartdiv" style="height: 250px; border: 2px dotted #c33; margin: 5px 0 20px 0;"></div>

<br />
Legend div:
<div id="legenddiv" style="border: 2px dotted #3f3; margin: 5px 0 20px 0;"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var chart;

var chartData = [{category:" "}];

AmCharts.ready(function() {
    // SERIAL CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.autoMarginOffset = 0;
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "category";
    chart.startDuration = 1;

    // AXES
    // category
    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.labelRotation = 45; // this line makes category values to be rotated
    categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
    categoryAxis.fillAlpha = 1;
    categoryAxis.fillColor = "#FAFAFA";
    categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";

    // value
    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.dashLength = 5;
    valueAxis.title = "Visitors from country";
    valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

    // GRAPH
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i ++) {
        chartData[0]["val"+i]  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
        var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.valueField = "val"+i;
        graph.title = "Graph #"+i;
        graph.type = "column";
        graph.lineAlpha = 0;
        graph.fillAlphas = 1;
        chart.addGraph(graph);
    }

    // LEGEND
    var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
    chart.addLegend(legend, "legenddiv");

    // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv");
});
```

CSS:

```
body { font-family: Verdana; padding: 15px;}

#legenddiv {
    height: 100px !important; /* force that height */
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This would solve the issue which the op was facing, but while we export the above chart as png or jpeg using AMcharts export functionality, I could see only the chart no legend, do you have any workaround for the same to appear.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
"legend": {
        "maxColumns": 1,
        "useGraphSettings": true
    }
```

i hope this would help you , max columns is set for lengent property , you will get all in one line

**EDIT**
as you cant see your char, because when we make legends in one column so your chart cant fit in existing height of your container so make change in css

```
#chartdiv {
width       : 100%;
height      : 1000px;
font-size   : 11px;
}
```

hope this will help

Comment: I see, but the legend is still in one column (I need in one row), the chart does not have enough space in this case...

Answer (score 1):

**To change Font-Family and Font-Size in Legends Label of Amcharts**

chart.legend.fontFamily= "sans";

chart.legend.fontSize= 24;